Pointcloud Tools not in Processing Toolbox QGIS 3.36.3-Maidenhead MAC
Pointcloud tools are not showing in Processing Toolbox.  I am using the most recent version of QGIS for MAC, 3.36.3-Maidenhead.
I see some others have had a similar problem before but no solution.
What can I do?

The version of PDAL included in the installer (2.3.0) is too old, the tools require PDAL 2.5 or later.

This question is similar to: Point Cloud Processing Tools on MacOS. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question to make it clear how it’s different.
